# Should I list a company on my resume after they bullied me out?

Tags: resume, work-environment, employer, australia, rights

I have been working for this medical practice as a receptionist for the past 3.5 years. They aren't exactly lawful in their operation and let's just say a few past employees had to go to Industrial Relations for compensation, such as a permanent full time employee's hours getting cut, leave accumulation "disappears" etc.

I became pregnant, and I was treated horribly, bullied, hours cut even though I am permanent part time, demoted to lower positions because they were trying to "help", basically being punished for becoming pregnant. I had a lot of leave accumulated, because I never take holidays and my payslips were showing I had next to none, how can this be?

So when I investigated it with my mother-in-law through all my payslips going back to when I became permanent, we found I had a lot of leave, and it was suddenly gone. So when I tried to take this up with my employer, I was sent nasty emails, personal matters I discussed with my CEO was discussed in these emails from managers to an accountant (and who else knows).

Basically I became a pain in the arse for them, even though I was doing what I was legally entitled to. I am currently looking for another job and was wondering **should I put the actual name of where I worked on my resume or not?** I would appreciate any help.

Comment: is there some reason you are not taking them to task legally?

Comment: @Kilisi OP doesn't say that she isn't and it's not really relevant to her question.

Comment: @Lilienthal it's a comment to elicit more info and it is relevant to how I would answer the actual question.

Comment: If Australia is like much of the developed world they will probably give a very basic reference for fear of legal consequences. If you're involved in a grievance process with them probably doubly so.

Answer (score 34):

I'm sorry you had to go through that situation.

I'd include the working experience and the name of the company in your CV. Otherwise, it will look either like a 3.5 years gap or that you are trying to hide something. They are going to ask you the name of your previous employer straight away, and why you haven't included it.

As suggested by Joe Strazzere, do not include the reference for your last position. If they request a refrence, explain what happened with honesty and provide them with, according to you, the best person to contact (i.e. someone who will most likely provide good feedback).

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, I totally agree, thanks for your suggestion. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Very often? How often do you change jobs? :-)

Answer (score 21):

> I am currently looking for another job and was wondering should I put
>   the actual name of where I worked on my resume or not?

Yes. You should include the name of your current company on your resume.

You can't leave it off - that would leave a gap in your resume. And you can't just leave a vague reference to an unnamed company - that would just raise suspicions. Obviously, you cannot lie and give a different company name.

You usually don't need to have a reference from every company where you have worked. In my locale at least, it's common to exclude a reference from your current company - since you don't want to let folks there know you are thinking of leaving.

Just come up with a handful of references from prior companies or other sources you can use when asked for references.

Answer (score 2):

If your work relations was good with someone in that company, you can always put that on the resume. When asked for reference, put his/her name, who can vouch for you and also convince potential recruiters that you are a good prospective employee.